# Navbar (pull-left / pull-right) doesn't align with following div elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The navbar doesn't align properly to the left and right-hand margin of my website. I am using Bootstrap's 'pull-left' & 'pull-right' functions.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Microbiology Bootstrap!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="pull-left">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="pull-right">
        <li><a href="#">By Industry</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">By Matrix</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">By Vial</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">All Studies</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Microbiology <br>Bootstrap</br></h1>
    <p>Find the validation study you need. <br>Search by industry, matrix or vial.</br></p>
  <a href="#">Learn More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nav {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}
```

**Illustration:**

```
    Home | Contents       By Industry | By Matrix | By Vials etc

Microbiology
Bootstrap
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are already loading bootstrap, you can achieve the same thing by using [bootstrap's navigation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). You will need two classes `navbar-left` and `navbar-right` on navbar's `ul`. Here is a sample code taken from bootstrap's documentation.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

You will have to add classes accordingly to your code. Add `navbar` class to the div having class `nav`.

Answer (score 1):

Use navbar-left , navbar-right instead of pull-left and pull-right